# Av = Bv for all v implies A = B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two $4\times3$ matrices such that $A\mathbb{v}=B\mathbb{v}$ for all $\mathbb{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, then $A=B$?

If it's not true, can you give me an example of it?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what do you think?

Comment: My guess is it's false. But I can't find an example.

Comment: This is similar in spirit to Ian's proof, but note that if $A\Bbb v = B \Bbb v$ for all $\Bbb v$ then $(A - B) \Bbb v = \Bbb 0$ for all $\Bbb v$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; a matrix is uniquely determined by the linear transformation it defines, and vice versa. One explicit proof is:

$$A=AI = A[e_1 \dots e_n] = [Ae_1 \dots Ae_n] \\
B=BI=B[e_1 \dots e_n] = [Be_1 \dots Be_n]$$

so because $Ae_i=Be_i$ we get $A=B$. Here $e_i$ is the $i$th unit coordinate vector.