# If $L_A = L_B$ then $A = B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem in Serge Lang's Introduction to linear algebra.

> Let $A$, $B$ be two $m \times n$ matrices. Assume that $AX = BX$ for all $n$-tuples $X$. Show that $A = B$. This can also be stated in the form: If $L_A = L_B$ then $A = B$.

As it says for all $n$-tuples $X$, then $X$ can also contain just $0$'s. In this case, I obtain $AX = BX = O$. Which would mean that $A$ is not always equal to $B$.
Where is my error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saying that $AX=BX$ for one particular $X$ is not the same as saying that $AX=BX$ for all choices of $X$.

Comment: Hint: Choose $X$ to be any of the standard basis vectors.

Comment: @lulu but it says for all n-tuples X, doesn't it? I'm confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Av = Bv for all v implies A = B?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254204/av-bv-for-all-v-implies-a-b)

Comment: @H-a-y-K Maybe we should mention a somewhat simpler example..
Consider the statement 'All real numbers are zero.' . Is this true just because, $0$, which is a real number, is zero?

Comment: @DeepakMS yes but, the problem says for all n-tuples X. X can also be a tuple containing n zeros. If there is at least one X for which $AX \neq BX$  then I think the implication that AX = BX is false. Because it is not true for all Xs. I think this is my error. But I can't understand why I am wrong here.
For example if a,b and x are numbers, ax = bx doesn't mean that a = b, because maybe x = 0.
Sorry, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: $ax = bx$ indeed means $a=b$ OR $x=0$. However, if $ax = bx$ for ALL $x$, then it means that the equation should hold for any $x$. Sure, $ax=bx$ does hold for $x=0$ and that particular case is taken care of even when $a \neq b$. But it does not mean that $a \neq b$ is a possibility for other values of$x$, say, for $x=1$.

Comment: Still not clear.  For numbers, if $ax=bx$ for all $x$ then of course $a=b$ (just take $x=1$).

Comment: @DeepakMS oh got it! I thought the question was saying thar A = B is ALWAYS true. Thanks!

Comment: @H-a-y-K It IS always true. What I mean is $A$ and $B$ doesn't change when $X$ changes and thus, if some set of specific values of$X$ implies that components of $A= $ components of $B$ then that means $A=B$ for any $X$, since $A$ and $B$ did not depend on $X$ in the first place.

Comment: Okay. But what if we start from O for X? I mean, for A != B A*O = B*O is always true. Now if we change X it will be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed seem to agree that $AX \neq BX$ for some $X$ means that the statement '$AX = BX$ for all X' is false.
Thus, it should be the case that $AX = BX $ for any $X$, and in particular, for $X=e_j$ for any $j$.
Now as mentioned in other answers, this would mean that $A = B$.

Comment: Okay. I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you choose $e_i$ a vector with an $1$ in the $i$-entry and zero elsewhere then
$Ae_i=Be_i$ by hypothesis. This implies that the $i$-column of $A,B$ are equal.

So by choosing all $e_1,...,e_n$, you get that matrices $A,B$ have the same columns, hence they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Given linear maps $T,T':\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, there exists unique $m\times n$ matrices $A$ and $A'$ such that $T(x)=Ax$ and $T'(x)=A'x$ for all $x,x'\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $e_i$ be the ith standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Clearly, $T(e_i)=Ae_i=A'e_i=T'(e_i)$. By construction of $A$, $Ae_i$ is the ith column of $A$. As the columns of $A$ and $A'$ are the same, $A=A'$.

Comment: I can understand this. But what if we choose a O vector instead of $e_i$?

Comment: @H-a-y-K Then $T(x)=T'(x)$ would be the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$. I'm not quite sure what the issue is exactly. You want to show that $A=A'$, assuming $T=T'$ holds.

Comment: Oh, so the question is "Can A be equal to B?"?
In this case, if X = 0, then, A can be equal to B. But is not always equal. Did I get it right?

Comment: The question is to show $A=B$ is true, assuming the two functions are equal. Considering $T(e_i)$ is infact a valid thing to do. No, you are wrong. $A=B$ always if $T=T'$. Recall that $T=T'$ means $T(x)=T'(x)$ $\textbf{for all}$ $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. So a natural line of thought is to ask yourself, what $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ gives me the desired result?

Comment: The matrices are unique. That is, there is only one matrix that satisfies the condition $T(x)=Ax$ $\textbf{for all}$ $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Therefore knowing what the matrix looks like is important. In which case, the matrix has columns $T(e_i)$ (for A, say).